# Concatenate 3 JSP field into date format

Tags: java, jsp

I have a date fields in jsp and I want to concatenate them in Java Class so that it will be save in database as a date format (**yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss**). here's my code:

**jsp:**

```
<label style="font-size: 17px;">MM</label><br>          
    <select name="pcmm" id="pcmm" class="sel" style="margin-left: 0; width: 51px;"> 
        <option selected="selected" value="" ><%=DateUtil.getDateSelectOptions("M") %></option>
    </select>
<label class="lab">DD</label>           
    <select name="pcdd" id="pcdd" class="sel" style="width: 51px;"> 
        <option selected="selected" value="" ><%=DateUtil.getDateSelectOptions("D") %></option>
    </select>
<label class="lab">YYYY</label>         
    <select name="pcyy" id="pcyy" class="sel" style="width: 66px;"> 
        <option selected="selected" value="" ><%=DateUtil.getDateSelectOptions("Y") %></option>
    </select>
```

**java class:**

```
    private String ror_period_covered;

    TblRevenueOfficialReciept ror = new TblRevenueOfficialReciept();
    Date date = new Date();

    ror.setRorDueDate(ror_due_date);
```

Comment: so really is the problem concatenating them or creating a date objects from the concatenated String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use SimpleDateFormat from the java.text package to convert the date string to date object:

```
String dd = request.getParameter("pcdd");
String mm = request.getParameter("pcmm");
String yyyy = request.getParameter("pcyy");
String dateStr = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd + " 00:00:00";

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
java.util.Date utilDate = format.parse(dateStr);
```

to update the date object to database,

```
// convert java.util.Date to java.sql.Date    
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
statement.setDate(column, sqlDate);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I think its `String dataStr = yyyy + "-" + mm + dd + "-" + " 00:00:00";`?

Comment: What variable should I call?
`ror.setRorDueDate(?);`

Comment: oh i had the dateStr formatted wrongly, i've updated the dateStr. assuming that you are setting the values from the jsp into your `ror` variable, you can do `ror.setRorDueDate(utilDate)`.

Comment: One more thing. May I ask why do I need to convert java.util.Date to java.sql.Date?